# How to highlight the active navbar link in svelte js

Tags: javascript, components, svelte

Consider I have two components in svelte js one of them is `Navbar` and the other is `NavbarLink`. I want to highlight the currently active link in navigation bar. So far I did it using jquery:

```
$(".navbar").children(".nav-link").click(function(event){
   $(this).addClass("active");
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
})
```

I am a newcomer to svelte js and still learning the basics. I want to get this kind of behavior in svelte js too. Can anyone tell me what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: In svelte tutorial add and remove classes: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>    
  let tabs = ["one", "two", "three"]
  let selected = tabs[0]
</script>

//your links
<li on:click={()=>selected = tabs[0]} class:selected={selected==="one"}>
<li on:click={()=>selected = tabs[1]} class:selected {selected==="two"}>
<li on:click={()=>selected = tabs[2]} class:selected={selected==="three"}>

//show if a specific tab is clicked
{#if selected === "one"}
..
{:else if selected === "two"}
..
{:else}
 ..
{/if}

<style>
  .active{
     //your css rules for active class
  }
</style>
```

Comment: this feels like a hack. idk maybe it's just me. :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922685/how-to-set-menu-item-to-active-in-sveltekit-app Has a much better answer