# How to set menu item to active in sveltekit app

Tags: javascript, html, sveltekit

I have been working on a sveltekit application and recently ran into an issue with my main navigation menu. when the application is loaded or refreshed the current menu item that corresponds with the current URL is not set to active. (i.e. menu item 'Home' would have URL of '/') I had a hard time finding anything useful online demonstrating how to set this up, but I have a working solution and thought I'd document it for others. It is very simple at the moment.

I have a nav.json file where I define any menus within my application, making it easy to organize menus. I import that at the top of the file and store it in an array for use later.

`import menuObj from '../nav/nav.json';`

`let sidebar = menuObj.menus[0].items;`

`onMount()` is just getting the current path when the nav component is loaded, and only runs once for me.

then - using `<svelte:window on:click={handlePageClick}/>` we can listen to any clicks on the page.

In the `handlePageClick(e)` method we pass the on:click event. Using that event we can capture the current `pathname` of the URL. this allows us to check the `pathname` against our `item.path` which is defined in the nav.json file I've imported and extracted using the `#each` method in our html. On the `<a>` we can set the class to active if the items route matches the current path.

here is the full implementation

```
<script>
    import menuObj from '../nav/nav.json';
    import {onMount} from "svelte";

    let path;
    let sidebar = menuObj.menus[0].items;

    onMount(() => {
        path = window.location.pathname;
    })

    function handlePageClick(e) {
        path = e.view.location.pathname;
    }

</script>

<svelte:window on:click={handlePageClick}/>
<nav class="sidebar">
    {#each sidebar as item, i}
        <a href={item.route} id="sidebar-menu-item-{item.id}" 
           class={path === item.route ? "item active" : "item"}
        >
            <i id="sidebar-menu-item-{item.id}-i" class="{item.icon}"></i>
        </a>
    {/each}
</nav>
```

I haven't found any drawbacks to this yet. I will update this question if I find anything.

Comment: There is a way to share knowledge like this on SO so it doesn't hang around as an 'unanswered' question. They give you a little 'I know the answer' checkbox when asking and you mark it and provide the answer. Here's the snippet of interest https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,both%20question%20and%20answer%20together.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not really a question, but I will add an answer anyway because your method is not necessary, SvelteKit already has a built in system for this:

```html
<script>
 import { page } from '$app/stores';
</script>

<a href={item.route} class="item" class:active={$page.url.pathname == item.route}>
 ...
</a>
```

**page** is a store like object that among other things hold the current path, it will automatically be updated with the new path

as a bonus:

**class:active** is an easy shorthand, removing that ternary expression there.

Comment: Thank you, much more elegant than what I was doing. I'm not sure where this is documented in sveltekit, I had trouble finding a solution like this but I did implement this and it is working.

Comment: how do I watch the $page.url.pathname property? I"m trying to save its value in `path` so I don't have to type as much (large menu)....but it doesn't update itself when routes change.

Comment: Use reactivity: `$: path = $page.url.pathname`